# Menger's theorem using Hall's theorem

Tags: graph-theory

Can somebody help me to prove Menger's theorem for directed graphs( edge version) using Hall's matching theorem.
where Menger's theorem states that: if x,y be two distinct vertices in a di-graph $G$ then minimum number of edges need to separate $x$ from $y$ is same as maximum number of edge disjoint $x-y$ paths. 
Hall's theorem states that, if $G(X,Y,E)$ is a bipartite graph then there exist a matching that saturates $X$ if and only if $N(S) \geq S$ for all $S \in V(G)$

Thanks for the help.